# ANTLR Tree Grammar for loops

Tags: parsing, for-loop, tree, while-loop, antlr

I'm trying to implement a parser by directly reading a treeWalker and implementing the commands needed for the compiler on the fly. So if I have a command like:

```
 statement
            :
            ^('WRITE' expression) 
            { 
                //Here is the command that is created by my Tree Parser
                ch.emitRO("OUT",0,0,0,"write out the value of ac");
                //and then I handle it in my other classes
            }
;
```

I want it to write OUT 0,0,0; to a file. That's my grammar.

I have a problem though with the loop section in my grammar it is:

```
'WHILE'^ expression 'DO' stat_seq 'ENDDO'
```

and in the tree parser:

```
doWhileStatement
:
^('WHILE' expression 'DO' stat_seq 'ENDDO')
;
```

What I want to do is directly parse the code from the while loop into the commands I need. I came up with this solution but it doesn't work:

```
doWhileStatement
        :
        ^('WHILE' e=expression head='DO'
            {
                int loopHead =((CommonTree) head).getTokenStartIndex();

            }

            stat_seq

            {
                if ($e.result==1) {
                     input.seek(loopHead);
                     doWhileStatement();
                }
            }
         'ENDDO')
;
```

for the record here are some of the other commands I've written:
(ignore the code written in brackets, it's for the generation of the commands in a text file.)

```
    stat_seq
            :
            (statement)+
            ;
statement
        :
        ^(':=' ID e=expression) { variables.put($ID.text,e); }
        | ^('WRITE' expression) 
        { 
            ch.emitRM("LDC",ac,$expression.result,0,"pass the expression value to the ac reg");
            ch.emitRO("OUT",ac,0,0,"write out the value of ac");
        }
        | ^('READ' ID)
        {
            ch.emitRO("IN",ac,0,0,"read value");
        }
        | ^('IF' expression 'THEN'
        {
            ch.emitRM("LDC",ac1,$expression.result,0,"pass the expression result to the ac reg");
            int savedLoc1 = ch.emitSkip(1);
        }
        sseq1=stat_seq  
        'ELSE'
        {
            int savedLoc2 = ch.emitSkip(1);
            ch.emitBackup(savedLoc1);
            ch.emitRM("JEQ",ac1,savedLoc2+1,0,"skip as many places as needed depending on the expression");
            ch.emitRestore();
        }
         sseq2=stat_seq
         {
            int savedLoc3 = ch.emitSkip(0);
            ch.emitBackup(savedLoc2);
            ch.emitRM("LDC",PC_REG,savedLoc3,0,"skip for the else command");
            ch.emitRestore();
         }

          'ENDIF')
        | doWhileStatement
        ;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it for everyone who has the same problem I did it like this and it's working:

```
^('WHILE'  

        {int c = input.index();}
        expression   

        {int s=input.index();}
        .* )// .* is a sequence of statements

        {
        int next = input.index(); // index of node following WHILE
        input.seek(c);
        match(input, Token.DOWN, null); 
        pushFollow(FOLLOW_expression_in_statement339);
        int condition = expression();

        state._fsp--;            
        //there is a problem here
        //expression() seemed to be reading from the grammar file and I couldn't
        //get it to read from the tree walker rule somehow
        //It printed something like no viable alt at input 'DOWN'
        //I googled it and found this mistake
        // So I copied the code from the normal while statement
        // And pasted it here and it works like a charm
        // Normally there should only be int condition = expression()   

        while ( condition == 1 ) {
            input.seek(s);
            stat_seq();//stat_seq is a sequence of statements: (statement ';')+
            input.seek(c);

            match(input, Token.DOWN, null); //Copied value from EvaluatorWalker.java
            //cause couldn't find another way to do it
            pushFollow(FOLLOW_expression_in_statement339);
            condition = expression();

            state._fsp--;
            System.out.println("condition:"+condition + " i:"+ variables.get("i"));
        }
        input.seek(next);
     }
```

I wrote the problem at the comments of my code. If anyone can help me out and answer this for me how to do it I would be grateful. It's so weird that there is nearly no feedback on a correct way to implement loops within a tree grammar on the fly.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: There is no feedback because it's (IMO) a messy way to tackle the problem. You're mixing all that code inside your grammar making the grammar very hard to maintain.

Comment: Of course it is a totally messy way, I agree with you. But I was sitting like 5 hours on it and couldn't find any good documentation on this subject and had to test it by myself or try random code from the internet, which was usually submitted ages ago. I just had to stick with the first one working.

I'm just making a project for the university and I've already spent a lot of time on the parsing.